Combining 'react-grid-layout' and 'react-virtualized'
We're using react-grid-layout to have a dashboard with resizable & draggable panels. It works perfect unless there are 5000 panels needed to be rendered. I thought about adding some virtualization to render panels more optimally. But, combining those 2 libraries is too hard to me.
Do you have any ideas how it's possible to achieve? Or, at least, add some virtualization to react-grid-layout?
Thank you in advance.
Here's the codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/unruffled-lederberg-gymnlz?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A36%2C30
